# Karate Runner: mvn: command not found The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

Tags: visual-studio-code, karate

I am using Karate Runner in vscode for automating api tests. I have install maven in my machine, don't have any issues there.

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.2 (40f52333136460af0dc0d7232c0dc0bcf0d9e117; 2019-08-27T09:06:16-06:00)
Maven home: /Applications/apache-maven-3.6.2
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

In vscode when I execute feature file using karate-runner I am getting below error message.

```
mvn: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

Please help.

not sure how to keep karate-cli options.

Comment: Please make sure the environment path variable is set correctly for mvn.

Comment: I'm getting this too. It used to work fine, but now I'm getting:

zsh:1: command not found: mvn
The terminal process "zsh '-c', 'mvn test-compile -f pom.xml test